# How to correctly translate past-tense from languages without Pluperfect?

Tags: translation

The slavic languages do not have a Pluperfect tense (except in very archaic use, and some others to, but for example) -

```
I asked &/or I had asked
Russian -ya sprosi
Ukrainian - ya zapytav
```

In English depending on context these are translated as `I had asked` or `I asked`. This also means that lengthy passages for example of recollections, would with all due technical correctness translate to English as `I had asked` `I had replied`, `I had walked` and the especially ugly `I had had` etc. 
Of course this severely disrupts the flow of language. Could someone support an argument (especially with a strong precedent) for translating what would be a pluperfect in English from a language which does not have a pluperfect into perfect in English. (Or the opposite precedent if the former is generally not considered acceptable).

P.S. I don't know if this or the English stackexchange are the proper board, please leave a comment if I'm not in the right place here.

Comment: I *think* this would be better on English. I will flag the mods to migrate.

Comment: Agreed, will send this to English.

Comment: They took it out of English - I don't know why, since it got upvoted, and I do think it is quite possible to give a technically well supported answer.